# Deploy application to Tezos

Tags: deploy

I have found https://github.com/Chain-of-Insight/pop-machine-glow which is interesting application, anyone knows how to deploy it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a technical tezos question

Comment: It is technical question.

Comment: Your question is about an application built on tezos, not about tezos itself. There's a difference.

Comment: Built on Tezos means that the questions is CONNECTED to TEZOS DIRECTLY. When the community is not for Tezos developers so what is the purpose of it? Do you want to focus only on baking empty blocks? ;-)

Comment: It is not clear *what* the problem is. Do you need help compiling the source code, compiling the storage, or deploying the contract?

Answer (score 0):

This is a smart contract written in LIGO, so you must compile it with the Ligo compiler which can be found here: https://ligolang.org/docs/intro/installation

Once you have compiled the source code, **and** the initial storage, you can publish the transaction through this web wallet: https://myxtzwallet.tokengate.io/

You need a private key associated with a positive tez balance in order to pay for the publication of a smart contract.